# Xp and leveling system PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ive looked at all the question that have been asked and with the answer, but i cannot seem to find a answer that suits me the best. What im trying to do is work on making a system that when a user is at a certain xp limit that go to the next level. and it shows how much xp is needed till the next xp.

So

```
lvl1 = 0 => lvl2 = 256 => lvl3 = 785 => lvl4 = 1656 => lvl5 = 2654
```

how would i go about doing that, so if xp is at certain amount show the amount and how much xp is needed for the next level.

Comment: Could this work?

function xpIncrease($amount) {
if ($amount>=$details['xp_needed']) {
    $amount-=$details['xp_needed'];
    $details['xp_needed']=$newValue; //user leveled up, update xp_needed
    xpIcrease($amount); //call it again because user may level up twice or more...
} else {
    //just add it with SQL
}
}

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this:

We have `users_xp` table in our db, with `user_xp_id` (primary key - auto increment),  `user_id` and `user_xp_amount` (default value: 0) fields. When we want to update the user xp amount we should do it like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

function update_user_xp($user_id, $amount, $mysqli) {
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE users_xp 
                    SET user_xp_amount=user_xp_amount+" . $amount . " 
                    WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
}

// we call this function like:
update_user_xp(4, 10, $mysqli); // user_id: 4, update with 10 points
```

when we want to get the actual user xp amount we can get it from our db table

```
function get_user_xp($user_id, $mysqli) {
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_xp_amount 
                           FROM users_xp 
                           WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
   $row = $sql->fetch_assoc();
   return $row['user_xp_amount'];

}

$xp = array('lvl1' => 0, 'lvl2' => 256, 'lvl3' => 785, 'lvl4' => 1656, 'lvl5' => 2654);

$my_xp = get_user_xp(4, $mysqli); // where 4 is my user id

for($i = 0; $i < count($xp); $i++) {
   if($my_xp == $xp[$i]) {
       echo 'I\'m on level ', ($i+1);
       break;
   }
   else {
       if(isset($xp[$i+1])) {
           if($my_xp > $xp[$i] && $my_xp <= $xp[$i + 1]) {
               echo 'My next level is ', ($i+2), ' and I need ', $xp[$i+1], ' more points for achieving it!';
               break;
            } else {
               echo 'My next level is ', ($i+1), ' and I need ', $xp[$i], ' more points for achieving it!';
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Later edit:**

```
CREATE TABLE `my_db_name`.`users_xp` (
`user_xp_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`user_id` BIGINT NOT NULL ,
`user_xp_amount` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: $my_xp = 325; that is teh set xp, id like to make it work, so when you post something it adds say 5xp to your xp. How would we do that ?-

Comment: can you give me a db table sql script for the table

Comment: I cannot upvote this as long as there is globals littered all over

Comment: what do you mean? sorry but I didn't understand :)

Comment: @MateiMihai It would be preferable to pass your database handler as an argument in your functions, than rely on `global`. See: [Why is Global State so Evil?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Comment: so than i would have to set a connect to db to use it

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /srv/disk8/1177900/www/cdn.g-mine.co.cc/Level System/index.php on line 15, i get this for  $mysqli->query("UPDATE users_xp

Answer (score 1):

Store your points in a DB table instead of in app-level logic for flexebility. Here is a proposed schema:

Table levels: `INT A_I P_K id, INT points, VARCHAR name`

Table users: `INT A_I P_K id, VARCHAR user, VARCHAR password, INT points, INT level_id` (basic fields)

Now for every user action that earns XP, update the user's points. Fetch from `levels` table all these rows and check them with the user's updated points to produce the results you need :) In the SQL Query, remember to `ORDER by points DESC` so that you can check for level ups easily inside a loop! If there is a level update, just update the user's `level_id` to match the corresponding `id` in the `levels` table. You can use something like `"SELECT levels.name FROM levels WHERE levels.id = $users_level_id"` to display the name of the level he is on.

I'd recommend a standard function `function xpAction(...)` that you call inside of all the XP-related actions that the user can perform. So if he adds a post and you're running `function addPost($data)`, just have a line inside it to call `xpAction` with the right parameters.