# SQL - how to get specific value of cell and save it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, discord.js

i have table like

```
+--------------------+-----+-------+
| id                 | xp  | level |
+--------------------+-----+-------+
| 1234567890         |  90 |     0 |
| 348832732647784460 | 168 |     0 |
| 441948056569511996 |  14 |     0 |
+--------------------+-----+-------+
```

where i need to select level for 2nd id and save it to a variable ex currlevel level will be 0 by default as i entered into the sql as default

my code is

```
con.query(`SELECT * FROM xp WHERE id= ${msg.author.id}, level= ${currlevel}` ,(err,results) => {
    if(err) throw err;


    if(results.length === 0)
    {
        con.query(`INSERT INTO xp (id, xp) VALUES ('${msg.author.id}', ${randomxp()})`)
    }
    else{
            let nxtLvl = currvevel * 300;
        if(nxtLvl <= currlevel){
            currlevel = currlevel + 1;

        }
        con.query(`UPDATE xp SET xp = ${results[0].xp + randomxp()} , level=${currlevel}  WHERE id= ${msg.author.id}`, err =>{
            console.log("successfully updated user xp! " + msg.author.id);
        })
    }

})
```

the code is in javascript (making a discord.js bot )
where con is

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'discord_bot'
}) ;
```

i am trying to set xp and leveling system for discord bot
also i am new to both js and sql

Comment: I don't understand the point of the first query

Comment: where it returns the user id ex the second id i need help how can i add currlevel (i added it myself may be wrong but the 1 querry looks like this)
```con.query(`SELECT * FROM xp WHERE id= ${msg.author.id} ,(err,results) => {```

Comment: how can i implement leveling system to it

Comment: *"how can i implement leveling system to it "* this question is in the gray area of considerd to be off topic for stackoverflow as  questions should be about programming problems/errors and not how you should/could implement something as that makes this question to broad to answer or primarily opinion-based..

Comment: actually this is a question because i really dont know about sql much

Comment: see the answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265628/5193536